# Spring boot API endpoint does not work after setting the DNS record

Tags: spring-boot, dns

I have a spring boot web service running on localhost:8000 with an embedded Apache Tomcat.

Frontend is developed using Angular and is running on nginx and port 80. Connection between front- and back-end is established with a REST API endpoint, i.e. /v1/getdata/...

We have a static IP and outside access is OK with this configuration. But after setting a DNS record, i.e. https://x.y.com for the static IP, the spring web server does not return data and ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error is occurred in Angular, although the front-end is loaded successfully on port 80.

The only server-side configurations in Spring app is server.port=8000 and CORS configs.

I have set [STATIC-IP]:8000 and https://x.y.com:8000 for the api address in Angular but neither worked. However accessing with static IP is still working.

I think there is a problem with SSL configuration.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you opened up port 8000 on any firewalls that are present on that server? Additionally if you trying to access it over SSL you need [Configure SSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl).

Comment: Yes I have configured the firewall and static ip is working. My server is behind a proxy in which the ssl is activated so I don't have SSL certificate.

Comment: @ImanH Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: @HosseinBadrnezhad AFAIK there was a problem in my http server. I managed to solve this problem by setting the nginx configuration:  *nginx
upstream backend {
  server back.ip.add.ress:port
}
server {
  server_name x.y.com
  location / {
    /* Angular dist */
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend
    ...
  }

Comment: @ImanH thank you. My problem was solved by turning off the cloudflare proxy.